Circuit diagram wanted for Aria AEQ-4 guitar preamp / tuner / equaliser
Requirement: Circuit diagram wanted for Aria AEQ-4 in-guitar preamp / equaliser / tuner module. This is a poplar unit but, surprisingly, the circuit diagram does not seem to be available on the internet. If someone could provide one it would be liable to be long term useful to others.
My usually quite capable web-searching abilities have failed to locate a circuit diagram. Does anyone have one (or can anyone improve on my web search capabilities ? :-) ).
A friend has asked me to repair an Aria AEQ-4 pre-amplifier/equaliser / tuner. This is a unit that is installed inside an acoustic guitar and that allows all strings to be correctly tuned and which provides an equalised output to a 1/4" jack.
The guitar is wanted for use in a recording session on Saturday afternoon. It's now (very) early Friday morning in NZ. A circuit diagram would help. There are only 3x dual opamps and a scattering of transistors but a nice helping of small vias with tracks running under the 6 pots to make life interesting. There is signal from the pickup and on both sections of a TL062 dual opamp, and on the volume control pot. After that the path grows colder. Repair will happen in time  (probably) but a circuit diagram would help significantly. Aria are not willing to provide a circuit diagram.
Image from here


Problem solved - but it's not an "answer" to the question - as a source of the circuit diagram would be a useful resource longer term. The problem was that a contact in the mono input jack had broken off. This grounds the plug tip and turns power on to the unit when a plug is inserted. This was not initially obvious as a "dead in the water" fault as the tuner portion has its own on button which livens the display and a dual opamp for tuning.
